# Backbone model.save() and fileReader fields

Tags: backbone.js, filereader

If I use a file chooser  to bring a file reader into a JavaScript program, create a filereader, read in a file, and then store this field in a backbone model, is it possible to send this information to a RESTful endpoint using model.save()?

If so, I have found no specific mention on http://backbonejs.org/, and all references I have found to this process discuss the use of plugins.

Are there some particular challenges I should be aware of, or am I making it out to be a lot harder than it seems?

I realize that if I had other fields in the model, then the RESTful request would probably need to be sent as a multipart request.  Does Backbone.js handle that alright?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, backbone won't take care of file-upload for you. You'll have to do it manually, there are many ways, one might look like :

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults :{
    uploadFile:'',
    name:''
  },
  upload:function(){
    //Normal file-upload logic here.success(function(response){
        this.set('uploadFile',response);
    });
  }
});
```